# Ошибка 'laravel/homestead' could not be found при наличии laravel/homestead box v. 10.0.0

Tags: php, laravel, virtualbox, vagrant, homestead

На ubuntu 18.04 добавил командой
`vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead`
Получил box successful added v 10.0.0
Проверил командой
`vagrant box list`
Получил
`laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 10.0.0)`
После выполнения команды

```
vagrant up
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
homestead: Box Provider: virtualbox
homestead: Box Version: ~> 9.5.0
==> homestead: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
homestead: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> homestead: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.5.1) for provider: virtualbox
homestead: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/9.5.1/providers/virtualbox.box
```

Не могу понять, почему начинается попытка скачать более старую версию 9.5.1 при наличии v10.0.0

Версия vagrant самая последняя Vagrant 2.2.10
Выполнил все предложения из темы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946837/box-laravel-homestead-could-not-be-found
но вопрос не решился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Дело в том, что в большинстве туториалов по установке laravel/homestead после команды

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

предлагают сделать

```
vagrant up
```

Возможно в более старых версиях vagrant это прокатывало, не могу сказать точно, но сейчас после добавления бокса нужно сделать

```
vagrant init laravel/homestead
```

И уже потом поднимать вагрант. Долго я искал эту команду, наткнулся случайно, очень жаль, что слишком часто приходится отвечать самому на свои же вопросы. Всегда задаюсь в таких случаях вопросом: "Неужели из той кучи людей, просмотревших этот вопрос, никто не знал этой команды? Или им просто было лень написать одну строку".